# Do I have to use "firebase deploy" after each change?

Tags: web, firebase-hosting

I'm still new to web development and I'm using Firebase to handle all my data right now.

I have everything up and running, but how do I make it so my Firebase website updates whenever I make a change to my files? Do I have to manually call `firebase deploy` after each change in order to see the updated site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To deploy your changes to the Firebase Hosting server, you will indeed have to run `firebase deploy`.

But normally when I develop an application, I run a local web server for the most part. I then only push the changes to Firebase Hosting when I have finished the feature/bugfix that I'm working on.

For local execution, I either use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or a [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) script that also [packs](http://webpack.github.io/) the files. The latter have the advantage that they can watch your local files for changes and execute the correct steps based on that.

Comment: `firebase serve` runs a local server at http://localhost:5000/ for you. When you make a change in source, just reload the page.

Comment: It definitely does Nick, thanks for pointing that out. Back when I write this answer (over 4 years ago), that wasn't the case yet iirc.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on a Angular 4 app with Firebase as a backend, so the steps are

```
$ ng build --prod
$ firebase deploy
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you're making html or css changes, you must do `ng-build --prod` then `firebase deploy`. (for Angular 6)

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you are doing and what you're trying to deploy.

There's three different areas to deploy to:

- Hosting - this is just a simple web server in which to house your HTML,  JavaScript and any other static files
- Database - your Firebase access rules are placed in here
- Storage - access rules to the file store, typically user submitted files

Typically you'll be developing your HTML and JavaScript files locally and testing them there. When you're ready to deploy to the hosting environment you'll typically deploy via `firebase deploy`, this will deploy all of the local files and rules to the Firebase servers.

If your question relates to just the database rules then there is no local version or instance of this, you need to deploy changes as you make them in order to make them active.

You can perform a rules update by issuing the command `firebase deploy --only database`. Just make sure you have a firebase.json file with `"database": { "rules": "firebase.rules.json" }`, or similar defined in it.

Bonus: Use BOLT to build the rules, it transpiles into a Firebase JSON rules file but makes development so much easier especially when your rules inevitably become more complicated.